# Update mesh in rigged character?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigging

Hi i cant seem to find any info about this. I have a rigged character that i have struggled with the wheight paint to get a it how i want it. And now i have tweaked and made some changes to the (copy)mesh a bit and now i want to replace the mesh that is under the rig with my updated mesh. Is there a nice way to do this without loosing all the weight paint work that i have done? Also have some blend shapes in the rigged mesh but i can live without those.

Comment: You can transfer weight paint information from mesh to mesh with the Data Transfer modifier. After applying that modifier just parent the mesh under the rig and add the Armature modifier to deform the mesh with the rig.

Comment: I shall add DataTransferM to the updated mesh before i parent it to to my rig? Do i generate data layers only from the vertex data of my old mesh, and do i do this before i parent it to my rig? And then  if i rig it do i use automatic weights or do i choose something else here?

Comment: The parenting shouldn't effect the Data Transfer modifier, only the positions of the meshes does (they should overlap as best as they can). Yes, generate data layers from vertex data of old mesh. You don't do automatic weights, you have weight information from the old mesh. Just simple parent and add the armature deform modifier (Or Ctrl-P -> Armature Deform - this adds the armature modifier for you so you don't have to manually add it)

Comment: Is there a way to transfer blendshapes?

Comment: That depends how much the blendshapes deform. You can use Shrinkwrap modifier to match small deformations of old mesh and then apply it is a blendshape. With more difficult cases it is possible but not easy. Requires python or baking vector displacement maps.